# An American Friend Cipher

Tags: cipher

An American friend of yours, JL for short, sent you the following message: "I can only say that 22. 21. 24. 21. 9. 3. 6. 9. 27. 2. 23."

The hint says the key may be in the initial part of this problem.

Comment: Is the key J + L = 10 + 12 = 22. Like that?